# Extract elements from List of Strings and assign it to a separate String

Tags: java, arrays, json, qjsonobject

I am new to Java and below is the requirement,
I have a JSONArray like :

```
[{"candidate_id":"agent_4","cluster_ID":"To_Be_Added","count":"2","utterance":"Can I text you a confirmation code on the line ending in 1544"}, {"candidate_id":"agent_11","cluster_ID":"To_Be_Added","count":"2","utterance":"Can I text you a confirmation code on the line ending in 3544"}, {"candidate_id":"agent_16","cluster_ID":"To_Be_Added","count":"63","utterance":"Hello Janet can you confirm your phone number?"}
```

The requirement is to extract keys from this JSONArray one by one and assign to to a JSONObject like :

```
{
"candidate_id": "agent_11",
"cluster_ID":"To_Be_Added",
"count":"63",
"utterance":"Can I text you a confirmation code on the line ending in 1544"

} and the rest as well as separate
```

Now, as of now I converted this JSONArray to list of Strings in which i will traverse and extract it one by one :

```
 for(int j=0;j<s.length(); j++) {
                if(s.contains("candidate_id")){
                    final String candidate_id =exampleList.get(j);
                    logger.info("print  candidate_id={}", candidate_id);
                   
                }
```

but it's not extracting the required results, what can be done here?

Final Output should look like :

```
Recommendation :{
{candidate_id: "agent_11",
cluster_ID":"To_Be_Added",
count":"63",
"utterance":"Can I text you a confirmation code on the line ending in 1544"
},
{candidate_id: "agent_13",
cluster_ID":"To_Be_Added",
count":"45",
"utterance":"Can I text you a confirmation code on the line ending in 1544"
}}
```

Comment: why do you do it by hand? you should use a library for json serialization/deserialization like jackson or gson

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a `getJSONObject()` method in `JSONArray`

```java
JSONArray array = new JSONArray()
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0)
```

You can just iterate over your `JSONArray` and create `JSONObject`s

**UPDATE**

Add this to `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20201115</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In order to use getJSONObject , do i have to add some dependency to pom?

Comment: @Kadev yes, i'll update my answer to include the dependency as well

Comment: Thanks, but when i do this and add the data to a grpc object, it is overriding the previous values:  Object object =  recommendationCandidate.get("candidate_id");
            Object object1 =  recommendationCandidate.get("utterance");

            abc.put("candidate_id", object);
            abc.put("cluster_id", object);
           // logger.debug("print abc{}", abc);
            eventBuilder.addAllRecommendationCandidates(abc.values());  --overriding

Comment: @kadev not sure if this is a typo but you are putting `object` inside both `candidate_id` and `cluster_id` of `abc`

Comment: Yes it was a typo, the things is I want to add these objects into GRPC object called eventBuilder which will carry the response as :  recommendationCandidates: [{candidate_id:"abc", text : " abc", count : 2},,,and so on ] , but currently is it being overridden